# Tiki Wiki Webmail

Tags: webmail, tiki-wiki

Hopefully one you you fine people can assist.
I just set up Tiki Wiki 24 on Ubuntu 20.4, Apache2 and MariaDB. I also have Dovecot and Postfix running on the same server. I want to use Tiki for one stop collaboration site. ant it seems totally doable. I have the webmail working finally but navigating to it is horrible.
I can not find a way to get an icon or menu link at the top level. Docs for the implementation are bare.

If you have some insight on this I would appreciate your direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to have a menu item available a top level that point directly to the Tiki Webmail.

By default, using the core Tiki menu (#42) you should be able to see it under "My account" (the user account area). But this menu is not customisable so not good for moving the Webmail item to the top-level.

Anyway, for everyday usage, I recommend you to create your own (user) menu with what you need display like you want. See: https://doc.tiki.org/Menu

Managing your own menu is super handy as you can modify/add absolutely anything; position, submenus, icons, colors, etc. You can also use a Tiki module inside the menu item to display dynamically content (like a category list that will point to pages), have wiki structure, etc.

As admin you still need the core menu (#42) but I reserve it for my administration only. I usually place in the bottom modules section with "admin" can view only. Check also my tutorial about this https://youtu.be/5fnFjNj4-Ss?t=312 - after 5mn.

Hope this helps.

---

Just a note about documentation, Tiki is an open source project and the documentation is made by the users and anyone can contribute and improve. Don't hesitate to add your input there.

Comment: Good answer B, i think there's a profile for one too that might help speed things up... weird, i can't find one, we should make one i think, just a tiny simple menu assigned to the top module zone... something for a TikiFest maybe?

Comment: Thank you. I will review and see what I can do.